# Doctrine ManyToMany optimize many queries

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity PointOfSale which has many to many relation with own tags and categories, and I'm looking how to optimize query when I'm loading 1k pointsOfSales from database with it's tags and categories.

mapping:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="pointsOfSales", fetch="EAGER")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"detail","list"})
 * @Serializer\MaxDepth(3)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pointOfSales_tags")
 **/
private $tags;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="pointsOfSales", fetch="EAGER")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"detail","list"})
 * @Serializer\MaxDepth(3)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pointOfSale_categories")
 **/
private $categories;
```

Thing is when I want to return json with categories and tags, there is always like 2k queries instead of one that I need.

I'm using this query:

```
    $POSqb = $this->createQueryBuilder('pos');
    ->leftJoin('pos.categories','c');
    ->leftJoin('pos.tags','t');

    $query = $POSqb->getQuery();
    return $query->execute();
```

It doesn't matter if I'm using JMS serializer or fetch eager or I'm using function to get content from entity, still doctrine will fetch category and tag for each pointOfSale with it's own query.

Is there way to optimize this to use mapping in single query? (pagination is not solution)

//EDIT: another select could look like this, all is selected and doctrine entity is mapped

```
$POSqb = $this->createQueryBuilder('pos')
    ->select('pos','c','t')
    ->leftJoin('pos.categories','c')
    ->leftJoin('pos.tags','t')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modified your query like this.

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT pos, c, t FROM YourBundle:ClassName pos LEFT JOIN pos.categories c LEFT JOIN pos.tags t ")->getResult();
```

Edited version. Put your bundle name and class name in FROM. Dont forget add use statement if you do this not in repository!

Comment: This is not working since query missing FROM statement, but whe I add ```FROM PointOfSale pos``` i get ```Error: Class 'PointOfSale' is not defined.``` Which is odd. But I'm not sure if 'trying' to force select all from joins will force to map entity classes.

Comment: Oh realy. Class name must looks like "FROM AmoMainBundle:Company c "